How can one collect interstellar dust using lasers or magnetic fields?
In this episode from Isaac Arthur about building artificial stars, he mentions that most mass (ignoring dark matter and energy) is not contained in the stars themselves, but in the interstellar dust the lurks between them. Roughly a single cubic light year of the interstellar medium has the same amount of mass that our sun has.
Isaac explained, that a thin sheet of material could be used to scoop it up. Graphene, which weighs about 0.77 milligrams per square meter, could be used for this purpose. A thin sheet across a square light year would contain (365 * 86400s * 300 000 000 m/s)^2 * 0.77 mg = 6.89e25 kg of carbon. That's only 10 times the mass of earth, an amount that could be star-lifted from a star.
At 9:33 in the video he suggests that the dust would preferably be collected using lasers or magnetic fields instead of sending a large thin sheet or a fleet of ships to physically scoop up the dust. However, he doesn't elaborate on it. The latter of those also seems odd to use, since magnetic fields get exponentially weaker over distance.
How can one collect interstellar dust using magnetic fields or lasers and why would that be preferably?

what in the sci-fi would make a thin sheet of graphene stretching across a square light year stay a thin sheet instead of collapsing into a big sphere of carbon?  it has 10 times the mass of the Earth

@ErinAnne Active support could be used to help the thin sheet from collapsing or the sheet could be made up out of serval smaller probes

I guess I should make my point more clearly:  I don't think that there is a grounded-in-reality-or-engineering answer to the "why would that be preferably" part of your question.  The giant thin graphene sheet is science fiction, and engineering it might be possible but there are too many unanswered questions to say anything useful about its merits versus other avenues of collecting particles.

@ErinAnne, I disagree with your point. This question seeks a realistic, science-based answer, and unfortunately, there isn't a dedicated science and futurism site on Stack Exchange. While we can't build an artificial star or go on an interstellar journey today, that doesn't mean the question can't be answered. There are many ways to answer questions about future technologies that are beyond our current capabilities, but for which we have a reasonable understanding of how they might be achieved.
